# How to print a dictionary which has lists in value position in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, printing

I was wondering how you would print the below dictionary values,

```
dict = {'eat': ['tea', 'ate'], 'tan': ['nat']}
```

in this format:

```
[['eat','tea','ate'],['tan','nat']]
```

I've tried get(), items() but they don't seem to get it right in this format, where the items and values are in a single list.

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_dict = {'eat': ['tea', 'ate'], 'tan': ['nat']}

# Use a list comprehension to create a new list called 'result'
# Iterate through the key-value pairs in 'my_dict'
# For each key and list of values (anagrams), create a new sublist
# The sublist starts with the key and appends the values (anagrams)
result = [[key] + values for key, values in my_dict.items()]

# Print the 'result' list containing sublists with keys and anagrams
print(result)
```

I am a beginner programer so i hope this will solve you problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a starred expression with a list comprehension to achieve this:

```py
d = {'eat': ['tea', 'ate'], 'tan': ['nat']}

lst = [[k, *v] for k, v in d.items()]

print(lst)
```

Output:

```py
[['eat', 'tea', 'ate'], ['tan', 'nat']]
```

Also be careful to not shadow built-ins. `dict` is reserved for the `dict` class.